# A simple example of an incomplete probability space?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

A probability space is *complete* if every subset of a set of measure zero is measurable. The probability space is incomplete if otherwise.

But is there a simple example of an incomplete probability space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the space $\{a,b,c\}$ with measurable sets $\{a,b\},\{c\},\{a,b,c\},\{\}$ where the measure of $\{a,b\}$ is 0 and the measure of $\{c\}$ 1. Then we have an incomplete measure space as $\{a\}$ (and $\{b\}$) are unmeasurable subsets of the null set $\{a,b\}$.